# python pandas how to compute on rows with same index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called resulttable that looks like:

```
df Index        Tag        Exp. m/z    Intensity    Norm_Intensity
114             C09.xls    1013.328    10000        0.125
114             C10.xls    1013.325    20000        0.115
114             C11.xls    1013.329    30000        0.128
180             C09.xls    1257.52     11000        0.215
180             C10.xls    1257.59     12000        0.220
196             C09.xls    1647.593    13000        0.432
196             C10.xls    1647.528    14000        0.450
196             C11.xls    1647.601    31000        0.585
```

where df Index values are the index values when resulttable is printed or exported to xls, Tag = str, and Exp. m/z, Intensity, and Norm_Intensity are float64. The tag values will be coming from the file names in a specified folder, so they can vary.

As you can see, each tag contains similar Exp. m/z values (like 1013.328, 1013.325, 1013.329) with their corresponding Intensity & Norm_Intensity values. These m/z values are to be considered the same, and **I was wondering if there is a way to do calculations such as mean, std, CV on the row values based on their df index values**. It doesn't matter if another dataframe needs to be made for the calculations.

```
resulttable_calc = resulttable.groupby(resulttable.index)
group_result = resulttable_calc.agg({'Exp. m/z':'mean','Intensity':'mean', 'Norm_Intensity':'mean'})
```

doesn't seem to do what I wanted. Doing so results in:

```
df Index               Exp. m/z    Intensity    Norm_Intensity
(114, 'C09.xls')       1013.328    10000        0.125
(114, 'C10.xls')       1013.325    20000        0.115
(114, 'C11.xls')       1013.329    30000        0.128
(180, 'C09.xls')       1257.52     11000        0.215
(180, 'C10.xls')       1257.59     12000        0.220
(196, 'C09.xls')       1647.593    13000        0.432
(196, 'C10.xls')       1647.528    14000        0.450
(196, 'C11.xls')       1647.601    31000        0.585
```

**EDIT**
The output of print(resulttable.index) is:

```
MultiIndex(levels[[114, 180, 196, ...........]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ......]],
           names=[None, 'Tag'])
```

I assume the labels correspond to each tag.

Comment: What does "Exp. m/z" mean? How do you calculate it? I think you can use `groupby` function, which provides calculated such as mean, std based on other columns values.

Comment: Exp. m/z are not calculated; they come from the files that I append in my code. Is there a way to use groupby on df Index values? I do use groupby in my code to make resulttable dataframe.

Comment: What is output for `df.index`?

Comment: @Andrew L I edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index is actually a `MultiIndex`. Since you're passing this to `groupby()` you're going to produce a grouping on every combination of the `MultiIndex`. I'm assuming you're looking to group by `df Index`- if so you'll need to group on `level=0`.

Try this:

```
resulttable_calc = resulttable.groupby(level=0)
group_result = resulttable_calc.agg({'Exp. m/z':'mean','Intensity':'mean', 'Norm_Intensity':'mean'})
```

Comment: That actually did the trick. Thank you!! Is there a book that I can buy that focuses on pandas? I wish to learn more in depth

Comment: @BongKyoSeo Yes- Wes McKinney I believe was the author of pandas. He has written a book on it.

Comment: is there a way to do this with another column at the same time? Now I have df Index along with a column called Cybi_Tag.  I tried doing `resulttable_calc = resulttable.groupby(level=0)['Cybi_Tag']` but it said Column not found: Cybi_Tag.

Comment: That's the correct syntax. Keep in mind column names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem and it worked for me too.

Before combining : [image: Dataset index was not unique]

After combining : [image]

```
news_df = news_df.groupby(level=0)
group_result = news_df.agg({'compound':'mean'})
```

`news_df` was my original dataframe.